# Add different types or UserControl in ItemControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, catel

I am using an ItemControl in my xaml code and it's itemsource is bound to a list of myCustomUserControl.

I use Catel MVVM framework

My question is : I have now a second type of UserControl with it's own view and viewmodel. Is it possible to bind the itemsource of my Itemcontrol with two types of UserControls ? If it's possible, how does i specify in the itemControl dataTemplate the different possible Views of my two usercontrols.

Here is the code of my ItemControl :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myCustomUserControl}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <Views:myCustomUserControlView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Thank you !

Comment: have you tried using the ItemTemplateSelector ?

Comment: A DataTemplate may be selected automatically by the value of its [`DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) property. In addition, ItemsControl has an [ItemTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx).

Comment: Thx ! I didn't know this property of itemControl. I find a really helpfull tutorial on this property (for someone who eventually has the same issue)  [link](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Comment: I think @Clemens should post this as answer instead of comment for future references.